# Can not save data to Database cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have table SubjectTutor who has column `id`, `subject_id`, `tutor_id`, `province_id`, `city_id`, `school_id`, `state_private` and `status`. I want to insert data into SubjectTutor table but the error is

> `province_id`, `city_id`, `school_id` and `state_private` will not
>   saved into table SubjectTutor, but `id`, `subject_id`, and `tutor_id`
>   will be saved.

this is controller. I also set `province_id`, `city_id`, `school_id` and `state_private` value.

```
public function admin_add_pack($standard_id=null) 
{
    $this->loadModel('Plan');
    $this->loadModel('SubjectTutor');
    $this->loadModel('Standard');
    $this->loadModel('Province');
    $this->loadModel('City');
    $this->loadModel('School');
    $this->loadModel('User');

    $standard_data = $this->Standard->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('Standard.id'=>$standard_id)));

    $province_id = 32;
    $city_id = 44;
    $school_id = 1855;
    $this->set('title_for_layout','Subject');   

    if(!empty($this->request->data))
    {           
        if (!isset($this->request->params['_Token']['key']) || ($this->request->params['_Token']['key'] != $this->request->params['_Token']['key'])) 
        {
            $blackHoleCallback = $this->Security->blackHoleCallback;
            $this->$blackHoleCallback();
        }

        //validate user data
        $this->SubjectTutor->set($this->request->data['SubjectTutor']);
        $this->SubjectTutor->setValidation('add');

        if ($this->SubjectTutor->validates()) 
        {
            // $this->request->data['Subject']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
            $userdata   =   $this->request->data['SubjectTutor'];
            $this->SubjectTutor->save($userdata,false);
            $subject_tutor_id   =   $this->SubjectTutor->id;

            $this->SubjectTutor->school_id = 1855;
            $this->SubjectTutor->province_id = 32;
            $this->SubjectTutor->city_id = 44;
            $this->SubjectTutor->state_private = 1;
            $this->Session->setFlash("Record has been added successfully", 'admin_flash_good');
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'standards', 'action'=>'subject_list',$standard_id));
        } 
        else 
        {   
            $this->Session->setFlash("Record has not been created", 'admin_flash_bad');
        }
    }
    $tutors =   $this->User->getStandardTutorList($standard_id);
    $subjects = $this->Subject->getStandardSubjectList($standard_id);
    $standards = $this->Standard->getStandardList();
    $provinces = $this->Province->getProvinceList();
    $cities = $this->City->getCityList();
    $schools = $this->School->getSchoolList();

    $this->set(compact('provinces'));
    $this->set(compact('standards','standard_id','province_id','city_id','school_id','standard_data','tutors','subjects','provinces','cities','schools','tutor_id'));
}
```

this is ctp file:

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1"> Select Tutor </label>
        <?php echo($this->Form->input('SubjectTutor.tutor_id', array('options'=>$tutors,'div'=>false, 'label'=>false, "class" => "form-control",'empty'=>'Select Tutor')));?>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1"> Select Standard </label>
        <?php echo ($this->Form->input('Subject.standard_id2', array('options'=>$standards,"div"=>false,"default"=>$standard_id,"label"=>false,"class"=>"form-control",'disabled'=>true))); ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Select Subject </label>
        <?php echo ($this->Form->input("SubjectTutor.subject_id", array('empty'=>'--Select Subject--', 'options'=>$subjects,"div"=>false,"label"=>false,"class"=>"form-control",'disabled'=>false))); ?>
</div>
</div>      
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Province </label>
        <?php echo ($this->Form->input("SubjectTutor.province_id", array('empty'=>'--Select Province--', 'options'=>$provinces,"div"=>false,"default"=>$province_id,"label"=>false,"class"=>"form-control",'disabled'=>true))); ?>
</div>
</div>          
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-6">
     <label for="exampleInputPassword1">City </label>
            <?php echo ($this->Form->input("SubjectTutor.city_id", array('empty'=>'--Select City--', 'options'=>$cities,"div"=>false,"default"=>$city_id,"label"=>false,"class"=>"form-control",'disabled'=>true))); ?>
</div>
</div>  
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">School </label>
        <?php echo ($this->Form->input("SubjectTutor.school_id", array('empty'=>'--Select School--', 'options'=>$schools,"div"=>false,"default"=>$school_id,"label"=>false,"class"=>"form-control",'disabled'=>true))); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the 'disabled' option for a field in a view, that field doesn't get set when the form data is saved..  Either use 'readonly' option instead, or set those values in the controller before you save (since you don't need user input anyway).  Or display the value to the user without pretending they have any input, and use hidden fields to pass the correct data.